# how to add extra wallpapers to your desktop in ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

i have recently switched to GNOME from unity and i just want to know how to add new background in it as it does'nt show the plus sign as shown in unity is there any other way to do it

Comment: Have you tried opening the background image in Image Viewer, and then right-clicking it? There should be an option to 'Set as Desktop Background'.